# Why doesn't Google Tag Manager insert my tags?

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have an issue with Google Tag Manager which I couldn't solve until now: I added a custom HTML tag to all pages (URL matches RegEx .*) but when I check the source code, I can find the code tag only on some pages and neither always.

Specifically I'm talking about the website http://www.ailolaquito.com. On some pages I can't find the code:

```
<script src="http://refnet.iteam-pro.com/track.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">try{ rn.track('8b120855'); }catch(e){}</script>
```

On other pages like http://www.ailolaquito.com/en/prices however I can find it. The same applies to other tags like for Bing Ads which I can find only on certain pages and not all though the RegEx expression should match all pages.

Any ideas what can be the reason and how it could be solved? Thanks a lot!

Comment: So, you didn't add that tag to all pages, if it is not there.

Comment: When you open the start page (http://www.ailolaquito.com), the Google Tag Manager code is added there as well. It's added to all pages. Plus, the rule (URL matches RegEx .*) should trigger that the Bing Ads tag and the tag mentioned above should be included on all pages, too, but they aren't. That's why I find it strange. What I noticed though when opening the source code in Safari is that on the pages where the tags are shown, it is tidy while on the ones where it isn't, the line breaks are missing.